# Como cerrar una pagina con javascript al dar click en el cierre principal

Tags: javascript, html

actualmente estoy creando una pagina en html, pero quisiera que al momento de dar click en el boton principal de cerrar de una ventana, osea aca...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y que me salga una ventana emergente con un mensaje de precaucion ... encontre que realizan con javascript pero con un boton o enlace, pero habra para que se trate directamente con el boton principal de cerrar.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
  <title>emergente</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    var confirmationMessage="\o/";

    e.returnValue= confirmationMessage;
    return confirmationMessage;
    });
</script>
<body >

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Podés usar el evento [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Reference/Events/beforeunload) de javascript, por ejemplo:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

  e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;     // Gecko, Trident, Chrome 34+
  return confirmationMessage;              // Gecko, WebKit, Chrome <34
});
```

---

#### Nota

> - Es importante que sepas que no se puede poner un `confirm/alert`
>   adentro del evento `beforeunload`.
> - Los textos son diferentes para cada browser.
> - No todos los browser soportan que se modifique el texto.

Comment: tambien funciona asi `window.onbeforeunload=function(e){return false}`

Comment: estoy planteando un codigo sencillo pero no me sale...acabo de editar mi pregunta

Comment: @Kevincs7 no te aparece el popup? A mi me funcionó, ese mismo ejemplo que copiaste me funciona. En qué browser lo estás probando? Te aparece un error?

Comment: estoy ejecutandolo en mozila firefox, no me funciona, como le doy en el boton cerrar, se cierra la pagina sin mostrarme un mensaje ni nada... sabes porque sea? mi codigo lo acabo de poner en mi pregunta(lo edite)

Comment: Si, ese mismo código probé y me funcionó, recién lo probé en la última versión de Mozilla y también funcionó. Chequeá eso.

Comment: estas ejecutando el mismo codigo que puse en mi pregunta?